# Beamer templating - resetting variables at start or end of frame

Tags: beamer

For a beamer theme, I'd like to provide two different kinds of frame titles. A normal one, plus one with an image background.

As far as I can see the best method to do this is to overload the `frametitle` template, such that when certain data is available, then  we choose the image version.

Since this data has to be global, we also need methods for resetting them either at the end of each frame or at the beginning.

If we look in `beamerbaseframe.sty`, this is exactly what `beamer` does with, say, `\insertframetitle`, it is reset to empty in the end part of the definition of the `beamer@frameslide` environment.

So my question is, how can we add our own variable resetting to this? (which would not be nullifying macros, but resetting them to default values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, come to think about it. Since the variables are only needed in the `frametitle` template, what is keeping me from ending the template by resetting these variables.

Comment: Did you solve your question in the mean time? Otherwise would you like to include a small example?

Comment: @samcarter I do have some functioning code, but very very ugly

Comment: Maybe you could add what you understand with "overload the frametitle template, such that when certain data is available" to make the question clearer? At least for me, I think I don't understand the question.